# can I remove the trailing zeros in a strings representation ([]byte) to compare strings?

Tags: string, go, utf-8, slice, rune

I need to compare strings in Go.
The problem is: I want to compare accented words (café) with its non-accented form (cafe).
The first thing I do is converting my accented `string` to its non-accented form with this:

you can run the code here: https://play.golang.org/p/-eRUQeujZET

But every time I do this transformation in a string it adds more runes in the end. The example above prints:

```
bytes: [99 97 102 101 0] string: cafe
```

As I need to compare the string returned from this process with its counterpart without the 'é' in the first place, I would need to remove the last `rune` (0) from the `[]byte`.

After running some tests I perceived that the last 0s (sometimes it adds more than one) don't change the string representation.

Am I missing something? Can I just remove all zeros in the end of the `[]byte`?

Here is my code to remove the 0s and compare the strings:

https://play.golang.org/p/HoueAGI4uUx

As we can't work alone in this field, here the articles I read to get to where I am now:

https://blog.golang.org/strings

https://blog.golang.org/normalization

https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your custom `Transform()` function:

```
func Transform(s string) ([]byte, error) {
    var t transform.Transformer
    t = transform.Chain(norm.NFD, runes.Remove(runes.In(unicode.Mn)), norm.NFC)
    dst := make([]byte, len(s))
    _, _, err := t.Transform(dst, []byte(s), true)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return dst, nil
}
```

In it you are using [`Transformer.Transform()`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/transform?tab=doc#Transformer) which also returns the number of bytes written to the destination. But you don't use that return value.

So simplest is to store the `nDst` return value, and slice the destination slice, because this holds the number of "useful" bytes in it (bytes beyond `nDst` will remain `0` as handed to you by the preceding `make()` call):

```
nDst, _, err := t.Transform(dst, []byte(s), true)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return dst[:nDst], nil
```

With this change, the returned slice will only contain the useful bytes without trailing zeros.

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LK8ImPuI02S)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 bytes: [99 97 102 101] string: cafe
```